# CSS Video background is whole screen, just need it for section

Tags: html, css

I have video background and it takes up the whole space of my website, when I want it to only cover a section of the website, the header section. I hope this makes sense.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div id="header" class="header-section">

                <video autoplay loop id="backgroundvideo">
                    <source src="videos/BackgroundVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="videos/BackgroundVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS to the video:

```
video#backgroundvideo {
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: background-size: cover is likely your problem

Comment: i removed background-size: cover and that did not fix the issue

Comment: i think you also need a space in your css selector between video and #backgroundvideo...is the css you have there being applied to your video??

Comment: yes it is @mgrenier what would your solution look like?

Comment: @user979331 can you recreate in a fiddle? you're using `position: fixed` which is most likely the issue as it takes the element out of the flow of the document, but it's hard to give you a solution without more

Comment: yes I agree with @jmore009 the combination of position: fixed and min-widht and height = 100% is likely causing your problem.

Comment: if you take fixed out and size your header according to what you need the video should cover the entire header only.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRwLj).

CSS

```
video#backgroundvideo {
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
}
.header-section {
width:100%;
height:200px;
background:#d7d7d7;
}
```

Comment: do you need to make sure `.header-section` has `position: relative;`?

Answer (score 1):

```
video#backgroundvideo{
position: absolute; 
right: 0px;
left:0px; 
top: 200px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
}
.header-section{
width:100%;
height:200px;
background:#d7d7d7;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context. How does your code change fixes the OP's problem